# import .tsv files into mysql with unique value

Tags: php, mysql, database, import, csv

user can upload only .tsv files.and i want to import this file into mysql with unique value.duplicates are not allowed.how to do this.I tried this code but it gives an error while inserting data.

```
<?php
    include_once("class/dbo.class.php");

$message = null;

$allowed_extensions = array('tsv');

$upload_path = 'uploads';

if (!empty($_FILES['file'])) {

    if ($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0) {

        // check extension
        $file = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $extension = array_pop($file);

        if (in_array($extension, $allowed_extensions)) {

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_path.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name']))
            {

                $filename = $upload_path.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];

                $content = file_get_contents($filename);

                $lines  = explode("\n", $content);

                $columns = explode("\t", $lines[0]);
                //print_r($columns);

                $sql_insert = "\n\nINSERT INTO tsv_table (";
                foreach ($columns as $column)
                {
                    if($column == end($columns))
                        $sql_insert .= "'".addslashes($column)."')";
                    else
                        $sql_insert .= "'".addslashes($column)."', ";
                }
                $sql_insert .= " VALUES\n";

                $total_lines = count($lines) -1;

                for($i=1;$i<$total_lines;$i++)
                {

                    $fields = explode("\t", $lines[$i]);
                    //print_r($fields);
                    //exit;
                    $sql_insert .= "(";
                    foreach ($fields as $field)
                    {
                        if($field == end($fields))
                            $sql_insert .= "'".addslashes($field)."'";
                        //else if($field == null)
                            //$sql_insert .= "'',";
                        else
                            $sql_insert .= "'".addslashes($field)."', ";
                    }
                    if(($i+1) == $total_lines)
                        $sql_insert .= ");";

                    else
                        $sql_insert .= "),\n";
                }

                    $d=new dbo();
                    dbo.$d->dml($sql_insert);
                    echo "Data imported successfully.";
            }

        } else {
            $message = '<span class="red">Only .tsv file format is allowed</span>';
        }

    } else {
        $message = '<span class="red">There was a problem with your file</span>';
    }

}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload TSV to MySQL</title>
    <link href="css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<section id="wrapper">  

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="file">Select file</label> <?php echo $message; ?></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="30" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" id="btn" class="fl_l" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>

</section>

</body>
</html>
```

error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ID', 'LAST_SCAN_DATE', 'NAME', 'MONSTER_CLASS', 'POWER_LEVEL', 'TRAINER', 'MELE' at line 1

.tsv file contains some fields having null values.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote the table columns.

Try

```
$sql_insert = "\n\nINSERT INTO tsv_table (";
foreach ($columns as $column)
{
    if($column == end($columns))
    $sql_insert .= addslashes($column).")";
    else
    $sql_insert .= addslashes($column)." ";
}
```

Comment: still not working:Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: it prints insert query like this: INSERT INTO tsv_table (ID ,LAST_SCAN_DATE ,NAME ,MONSTER_CLASS ,POWER_LEVEL ,TRAINER ,MELEE_ATTACK ,DEF_CRUSHING ,DEF_SLASHING ,DEF_PIERCING ,DEF_FIRE ,DEF_COLD ,DEF_ELEC ,DEF_WIND ,DEF_HOLY ,DEF_DARK ,DEF_SOUL ,DEF_VOID ,DEBUFFS_AFFECTED) VALUES ('1', '2013-05-04T18:34:43.136Z', 'Green Slime', 'COMMON', '''''CRUSHING', 'AVERAGE', 'AVERAGE', 'AVERAGE', 'WEAK', 'WEAK', 'AVERAGE', 'RESISTANT', 'RESISTANT', 'AVERAGE', 'AVERAGE', 'AVERAGE', ''), ('2', '2013-05-04T18:35:41.138Z', 'Tentacle Monster', 'COMMON', '''''PIERCING', ........

Comment: I notice the POWER_LEVEL and TRAINER null values are not separated by commas, hence the count doesn't match. What if you uncomment the else if($field==null) statement

Comment: nope.not working it gives an error:Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.

Comment: hello @Peter Etelej , do you have any slution?